# What visualization libraries are available for Fortran?

Tags: fortran, visualization

What visualization open sources or free software libraries are available for the Fortran programming language? Are there any similar to MatPlotLib for Python, for Fortran?
If not, most scientists require visualization not only to generate some outputs but also to investigate data trends, which is missing in Fortran although its speed in computation is well-known.

Note:

This question is intended to discover available, or planned to be available, graphical libraries for Fortran. It is clearly not going to compare different packages among different programming languages.

The flexibility, quality of outputs, interactivity, multi-dimensionality, free/open source etc are of factors to be discovered.

Comment: You could look at mixed language... you don't have to do your visualisation in Fortran. With f2py or fwrap you can easily call Fortran from Python where you have the full flexibility of Matplotlib (or any other Python library).

Comment: Your mentioned method is what I am using currently, however, there are difficulties there. I initially develop my code in Python then translate it to Fortran (for the case the speed is a need) then compile it then finally invoke the Fortran functions via Python. It is not easy however to translate Python code to Fortran all the time. Two series of debugging are required: one for each language.

Comment: Consider using numpy/scipy, or PETSc/SLAPc. All these use fast compiled code for the gruntwork, and Python to express the high-level operation. The code will be simpler, and usually faster, than what you will produce by yourself. It also eliminates the conversion step to fortran.

Comment: @PhilH The method you mentioned is what I am using now however I have sometime to write code in Fortran for the speed which I cannot have such a performance even using Numpy! My benchmarks for computation intensive parts proved me that Fortran cannot be easily beaten.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think there are some libraries available, which allow you to do directly some rendering of data from Fortran, however nothing like MatPlotLib, as far as I know.
*Edit: Here is a short link collection:*

- http://www.astro.caltech.edu/~tjp/pgplot/
- http://sourceforge.net/projects/gnuplotfortran/
- http://www.mps.mpg.de/dislin/
- http://www.vigyan.com/desl/FLAVOR.HTM (maybe not exactly matching here)

But the main point of the typical Fortran application is not the visualization of the data, but its generation. Typically you produce some output file, which can then be read by gnuplot or some other visualization tool. A common data container format is for example HDF5.
If there is still some need for direct visualization from within the Fortran application, you can use the ISO_C_Binding to interface with any C-Library, which should provide you with plentiful options. Still for these cases it is likely, that you will need to generate some wrapping layer around the C-API to provide an convenient usage in the Fortran application.

Comment: I've used dislin, plplot and pgplot (a long time ago).  All three provide Fortran bindings; the first two Fortran 90 bindings.  So in these cases you don't need to create your own wrapper.

Comment: I would like to mention that none of the listed libraries is comparable with MatPlotLib in terms of easiness in application and quality of outputs. Also for some you need to save your output as files and then visualize them. Since I was hopeless to find the competitive replacement I accepted the fact, I mean the answer.

Comment: @Developer - With what part of DISLIN's output are you unsatisfied? I've used it to create plots which were accepted by mag. editor. It also enables you to create plots "in program" (no need to create output files and then visualize them).

Comment: @M.S.B. Yes, indeed I listed only those libraries, which came to my mind with dedicated Fortran support. The wrapping comment is just on the ISO_C_Binding to an arbitrary C Interface...

Comment: @Rock: I had some experiences in the past. I should say I could NOT compile DISLIN through GFortran. Always there are something missing! I tried however using Python binding of DISLIN which WAS successful. However if not all most graphs are not interactive which is intrinsic part of each graph in MatPlotLib. Also the graphical quality (at least on screen) is lower than what I get in MatPlotLib. Furthermore, MatPlotLib is fully free while DISLIN has some license considerations.

Comment: @Developer - I have not experience any problems (that I remember), but if you have any trouble with it try the dislin google-group, or contact Michels (the author) directly. He is a great guy, helpful.

Answer (score 5):

*Just to make this list, a bit more complete ...*

- [PLPLOT](http://plplot.sourceforge.net/)
- [GINO Suite](http://www.gino-graphics.com/)
- [Winteracter](http://www.winteracter.com/)
- [NCAR](http://ngwww.ucar.edu/) (outdated)

Comment: First, it was useful to list other products. Note that GINO, Winteractor are *commercial* products.

Comment: @Developer - Sorry about that. I could've swore that open source/free wasn't there when I read the question. (I mean it probably was, but ... ugh, never mind.)

Answer (score 4):

There is also [gtk-fortran](https://github.com/vmagnin/gtk-fortran/wiki).

gtk-fortran offers also an interface to PLplot (>=5.13 in the GTK 3 branch).

Comment: This work (GTK-Fortran) **has no** graph functionality e.g. what we can find in others. It is however a good work to generate GUI for Fortran.

Answer (score 3):

Free: Mjograph (2d plots only) and Veusz (2d and 3d plots)

Perhaps you can generate csv or simple space-delimited files with your Python/Compiled-Fortran code, and process using 2d plotting software like Mjograph and/or 2d/3d software like Veusz.  Mjograph is only available via Mac and/or Java platform. Veusz is scriptable with Python, it was built using Python with Qt & Numpy, in fact the save file is just a plain Python script, and is comparable to gnuplot (at least in terms of ease of use).  The tutorial with veusz clearly shows what the capabilities are.  I like that it starts you off with the GUI, but you can wean off to pure scripting afterwards.

Mjograph: http://www.ochiailab.dnj.ynu.ac.jp/mjograph/
Veusz: https://veusz.github.io/

Veusz seems a little more natural compared to dumping data into Matlab or Mathematica.  At least if you are used to pushing python and Fortran around with Bash scripts on linux.

If you insist on 3d data, I would take a second look at DISLIN, it can work quite well depending on what you need to visualize. The license is quite affordable for commericial-use.  If using for academic use it's free.

Answer (score 1):

Typically, a Fortran user creates massive data files then uses some 3rd party visualization software that fits the application.  There are a couple of libraries that directly link to Fortran.  [Dislin](http://www.dislin.de/) is a fantastic one (particularly on Windows).  It has a ton of documentation and once the learning curve is over you can create great GUI's as well. [GnuplotFortran](http://gnuplotfortran.sourceforge.net/) is an interface from Fortran to the standard gnuplot.  I've yet to use it, but hear good things.

Answer (score 0):

My choice would be something like PV-WAVE from Visual Numerics Inc. -- lately bought out by Rogue Wave Solutions.

This uses a big library of Fortran routines and employs its own special 4G language to speed up coding your own custom data displays.

This product is not cheap -- it was developed for applications like seismic data analysis, wind speed/direction data representation, simulation of things like airfoil flow, injection-molding cooling, stress analysis, etc -- but it is the best that I've seen.
Very clear documentation, examples supplied for each library sub-program, good help guide, direct line to tech support.
Leaves MatLab for dead.